# Upgrading cookie authentication in a SPA to .NET Core 2.0

Tags: .net, authentication, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I have a SPA I wish to upgrade to .NET Core 2.0 Web API

Out of the box .NET Core has very poor cookie authentication for SPA as all the middleware assumes that you want to redirect to `/Account/Login`.

In a single page application an authentication redirection is useless (there is no login page) - instead I need a 401 response that tells the client side JS to ask the user to log in.

To work around this in .NET Core 1.1 I had to allow the `AutomaticChallenge` to fire and then override the event...

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
{
    var c = options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie;
    c.AuthenticationScheme = "MyScheme";
    c.CookieName = "MyCookieName";
    c.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;

    // This is a total cludge: AutomaticChallenge causes something deep in .NET to auto respond with a 302 redirect to ~/account/login
    c.AutomaticChallenge = true;
    c.LoginPath = PathString.Empty; // LoginPath defaults to ~/account/login
    c.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
         // Override the 302 redirection with the 401 we actually want 
         OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
         {
             context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
             return Task.FromResult(0);
         }
     };
})
```

This was a cludge, but it worked. In .NET Core 2.0 it has been deprecated.

I've tried moving this to `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie`, but while the cookie name and other properties are configured the `CookieAuthenticationEvents.OnRedirectToLogin` is ignored.

I've tried moving this to `services.AddAuthentication(...).AddCookie()` as suggested [in the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x), but those settings are just ignored.  `services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>` behaves the same way.

**How do I set up a .NET Core 2.0 Web API so that if the request does not have a valid authentication cookie it returns an HTTP 401 status?**

Comment: SPA always had issue working forms/cookies authentication and vise versa. If you do SPA then do JSON Web Tokens Authentication and Run all back end services as web API.

Comment: @Jeyara you make it sound like this is a fundamental issue with SPA. It isn't. Cookies != Forms, whether a service returns a bearer token or a cookie should be an implementation detail, not locked into whether the username/password request is a form or JSON post. It's not even the issue here: I have an SPA that works with either (both are supported so some password managers work) and a success setting the cookie from 1.1, but that fails in 2 because it assumes I always want a form redirect.

Answer (score 0):

In the Authentication 2.0 stack, the configuration of the application cookie is no longer part of identityOptions. Please see [Auth 2.0 Changes](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/262)

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
        {
            o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToLogin = (ctx) =>
                {
                    if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                    {
                        ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (ctx) =>
                {
                    if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                    {
                        ctx.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but if you read the question to the end you'll see that I already tried that.

Comment: I copy/pasted this code from my API production code. Isn't working on your side? I have 4 APIs that work this way

Comment: that's cool. Any upgraded from 1.1 with the identity middleware?

Comment: I initially wrote all of them in Core 1.0 with Identity Core 1.0, then upgraded to 1.1 and few days ago upgraded to 2.0